# Вложенные циклы в С++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно вывести фигуры на экран с помощью циклов. Мне нужен код для фигур Д и Е, думаю если я узнаю как их сделать то другие не будут проблемными. Я уже сделал фигуры а, б, и, к но дальше уже голова не варит.
`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // форма И
    {
        for (int j = 10; j > i; j--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) //Форма Б
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //форма К
    {
        for (int j = 10; j > i + 1; j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Форма А
    {
        for (int j = 10; j > i; j--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (int k = -1; k < i; k++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }`
```

[image: На фото фигуры которые мне нужно вывести]

Comment: Ну д) и е) это, очевидно, соответственно сумма зон с в), г) и ж), з). А как отрисовывали а,б и к можно посмотреть код?

Comment: Как мне редактировать свой вопрос? Я не могу найти кнопки

Comment: Кнопка "Править" слева внизу под вопросом

Comment: Подсказка: для рисования любой из этих фигур будет достаточно реализовать заполнение треугольников-четвертей по условию, а потом заполнять один или два таких треугольника.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вот для Д)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << (
                 (j >= i && j < 10 - i) ||
                 (j <= i && j >= 10 - i - 1)
                 ? "*" : " ");
        }

    cout << endl;
    }
```

Вот - для Е)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << (
                 (j > i && j < 10 - i-1) ||
                 (j < i && j >= 10 - i)
                 ? " " : "*");
        }

    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: объясните как работает все то после cout

Comment: Либо верняя часть (первая часть условия), либо нижняя (вторая часть условия). Если условие истинно - выводим `*`, если ложно - `' '` (пробел). Во второй части почти все то же самое.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я понял. Дальше думаю сам разберусь легко